# I'm trying to find a way do put a live updated view of a webpage on my desktop

Tags: windows-10

There was a feature in W98 that would let you put a picture from a website on your desktop, and it would update whenever the site changed the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Active Desktop died with Windows XP due to security concerns.

There are third-party applications that will place a maximized window over your desktop which will display a web page, but this arguably isn't much different than maximizing a normal browser window (that is, you most likely won't be able to access desktop icons or the Windows right-click menu).

If you can live without access to desktop icons, etc. (i.e. you don't mind using just the Windows taskbar or keyboard shortcuts), you may wish to try a semi-popular freeware application called [Wallpaper WebPage](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/WallpaperWebPage.shtml). It was created back in 2011 for Windows 7 but it will likely work with Windows 10. Its primary advantage over a maximized browser window is that application windows will always appear over top of it.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried the wallpaper web page, but that really doesn't do what I'm after.   Still, now I know what it was called which will make my search easier.

Comment: You're welcome. And thank you. It may not be helpful to you either, but it is also possible to update the Windows desktop background from automated scripts, such as those you can produce with [Python](https://www.python.org/). Therefore, while it certainly still wouldn't be Active Desktop, you could possibly update your Windows wallpaper based on images retrieved from the net (again, via Python) or even potentially from screenshots of webpages (via Python. Chrome and Selenium).